# Sum of Two Table with Left Join Multiply with First Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have two table with value like

```
Table1
invoice  item      Amount
05       banana    100
05       Apple     100
02       Avacado   150
```

here i have another `table2` with different values

```
Table2
ID           Paid
05           50
05           20
02           0
```

so i here i am trying to get the total invoice Amount and of `table1` and subtract the  paid amount and show the query

so here i already tried this but my `table2` paid amount get multiplied with the table1 invoice count

query i written

```
select t1. invoice, sum(t1.amount)-sum(t2.paid) as left_amt 
 from table1 as t1 
 left join table2 as t2 on t1.invoice=t2.id 
 group by t1.invoice
```

i want expected output like this

```
invoice      left_amt
05           130
02           150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a separate grouping of the two tables before joining them like

```
select ID, INV - coalesce(PAID,0) amt_left from
(select invoice, sum(amount) INV from table1 group by invoice) tbl1
 left join
(select ID, sum(paid) PAID from table2 group by ID) tbl2
 on invoice=id
```

**Edit**: changed it to `left join` in combination with `coalesce()`. This will work even if no payment record exists.

Answer (score 1):

Since I already wrote this out, here's my version:

`select t1. invoice, sum(t1.amount)-t2.paid as left_amt 
 from table1 as t1 
 left join (select t2.id, sum(t2.Paid) as paid
            from table2 as t2
            group by t2.id) as t2
            on t1.invoice = t2.id 
 group by t1.invoice`

You can play with the code on SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/185777/9/0).

Comment: that helped dude

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I think @cars10m has a good point - my answer will fail if there are no payment records. You can fix this, though, by changing the "left join" to a "left outer join"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.invoice, sum(t1.amount) as inv_amount, 
   inv_amount-t2sum.inv_paid as left_amt
FROM table1 as t1 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT id as invoice, sum(paid) as inv_paid
   FROM table2
   GROUP BY id
   ) as t2sum on t1.invoice=t2sum.invoice
group by t1.invoice;
```